# Finding maximum weight sequence of points in positive quadrant

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a sequence of weighted points in the positive quadrant we have to find
the maximum weight sequence of points so that each successive point is contained in the
rectangle formed by the previous point and the origin.

I am interested in a DP algorithm for this problem.

Comment: By the previous *point*, or by the previous *points*? How is it you're seeing a rectangle being formed by two points (origin and the other one)? This is a good question for an ascii award (:

Comment: previous "point". and origin and point under consideration are opposite corners of the rectangle @Rubens

Answer (score 1):

This problem is really asking for the longest increasing subsequence. An O(N log N) algorithm for solving this is described on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

### Easier O(N²) algorithm

I am assuming you have integer points. If you don't, you can use coordinate compression to place your points in an N x N grid.

So you have an two-dimensional number array W where each number is the weight assigned to that coordinate. You now have a recurrence:

```
// T(w,h) = "Maximum weight of the point sequence in sub-grid (w,h)"
T(0,0) = W(0,0)
T(0,y) = W(0,y)+T(0,y-1)
T(x,0) = W(x,0)+T(x-1,0)
T(x,y) = W(x,y)+max(T(x-1,y),T(x,y-1))
```

You can either [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the recurrence T (O(N²) space) or compute it one row at a time (O(N) space). Both algorithms will use O(N²) time.

You can try computing this recurrence using pen and paper to see how it works.